Is anti-realism anti science?
I would think that science by definition would need to have the notion of an outside world independent of itself along with other people and other minds to be able to perform and verify findings. Seems like it would be at odds with the field itself.
I got to thinking about it from here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscrutability_of_reference#Overview
Personally I think Quine might be wrong here and think he might not get language to think there is no set translation for anything, despite what I think is plenty of evidence for the contrary. I also think that his notion of not being able to determine someone’s ontological commitments from what they say isn’t right either and sounds more like a case of wanting your cake and eating it too since from what I gather his view does lead to relativism or skepticism even if he says otherwise. I guess philosophers are just people. I mean writing something and posting it for others to read by default means you accept other people and minds exist. Otherwise that would raise some odd questions about what you’re doing.
But I’m more referring to what Putnam mentioned further down where he uses that theory to challenge a mind independent world (which I think is extreme because then who are you talking to). I mean…we use words to refer to other things all the time, stuff that exists out there (or in our heads). I don’t think there is an inscrutability of reference because you can determine what people mean by context, even more so I would argue reification isn’t a fallacy.
But yeah, sorry for the mess but I just find it odd to argue for anti-realism but advocate for science because by definition you would have to accept realism to do science. Otherwise I would think you wouldn’t be able to do science because not only would you not be able to measure things but also they could never be verified or reviewed.

OP: "science by definition would need to have the notion of an outside world"
Indeed, scientific research is done by scientists who consider the possibilities of undiscovered nature to try to discover which of those possibilities are actualities.
Should we include the scientists' existential existencies as part of the scientific venture?  This is what Heidegger came up with in his existential conception of science.

The existential conception understands science as a way of existence
and thus as a mode of Being-in-the-world, which discovers or discloses
either entities or Being.
SZ 357

Being-in-the-world is conceived as a "unitary phenomenon" describing Dasein's existence and connection with the world.  The whole 'Being' part is quite indeterminate and probably indigestible for a realist inclination.  Nevertheless, including existential existence in the venture makes one conception of science that includes the possibilities of undiscovered nature—or "outer world" as the OP puts it.

We can say that heavenly bodies follow their courses and “are,” even
if no one anywhere, or in any way, represents them. We say this. But
if we say this, then we must also concede that when there is no
representing, “then” there is also no “then” and no “when.”
And so, everything is set up by the human and unfolds at its behest.
This could be swiftly foreclosed on, were this ever a domain of
“conclusions” and “deductions.”
A being is not without being.
(Heidegger, On Inception)

That is to say, the determination of entities – i.e. things that are : beings – depends on being, (which is a lot more tricky to define than one might expect).

This sounds like Protagoras' homo mensuras thesis "Man is the measure of all things, of things that are, that they are, of things that are not, that they are not."

@mudskipper It does sound like Protagoras' thesis. However, Dasein as being-in-the-world also includes 'the world' (however vague and undiscovered). So it's is not just 'Man', it's a more nuanced position.

Is there an English translation for what that means? Being isn't really a unitary phenomenon, it's just the brain. It's actually pretty digestible from a realist perspective, especially since we are assuming an external world independent of us. But the determination of entities doesn't depend on being, these things existed before us and will exist after. I feel like there is always a simpler way to say these things. Being, though, isn't really that tricky. All that you are is the brain, stop it and you stop too. Seems simple enough.

I'd also add Heidegger is sorta wrong that everything is set up by the human mind. Maybe our understanding of things might be, but the world and everything else isn't (and yeah I get "concepts" and all that blah blah). There is a "then" and a "when" and neither requires representation. But also the determination of entities doesn't depend on being, as shown by them existing prior to us. His philosophy is good poetry IMO but it's not reality, nor is it really related to my question. What I said is whether anti-realism is anti science since science seems to presuppose realism.

Re."Being isn't really a unitary phenomenon, it's just the brain." Not at all. When you ask yourself "what & where am I?" you're not just a brain. You are existence (including matter, life, consciousness: variously scientifically problematic) existing somewhere (also mysterious). It's full of unknowns but there is it, a fait accompli, experiencable without knowing all the nuts and bolts, boiled down to the minimal concept of being-in-the-world. Descartes' cogito ergo sum was more minimal but neglected the world component, which later caused a bit of problem ontologically.

In On Inception Heidegger has indeed moved on to poetry. A long meditation on Being over 3 books: Contributions, On Inception, Mindfulness. Being & Time is more scientific. "Maybe our understanding of things might be [set up], but the world and everything else isn't". Indeed, all the concepts we use are set up, except for 'the world' and existence, which is the ontological point of departure. Everything else is undetermined out there in the world. We determine things that can be accepted as existing priorly, but they're still set-up determinations. It's not realism but it can be science.

I understand the difficulty. For example Newton's law of universal gravitation F = (G m1 m2)/r^2, didn't this exist prior to Newton's formulation of it? When it was discovered it was accepted that it existed before it was discovered. However no one had heard if it before then. And then Einstein's theory of General Relativity came along with a more accurate model of reality. We don't know if there will be another advancement. Reality is unknown out there in the world; we have human-made scientific models and determinations to describe it. Scientifically they exist as realist determinations.

I think science contemplates a range of theories from "instrumental" (i.e., just match the data) to "realistic" (i.e., tell me what is actually "out there").
In the former category, we could put Quantum Mechanics - there are several formulations of quantum mechanics that all match the data perfectly, but the math is purely instrumental - it requires an interpretation to make it connect to what is happening in a realist sense; unfortunately, there are many valid interpretations and they differ in their metaphysical commitments.
In the latter category, we have theories like genetics, evolution, and classical mechanics of mesoscopic objects. These are clearly singling out a unique "particular" that is operative vs just "get me the correct results" of QM.
